# WordPress: Theme config error whenever I am activating the plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

Pixzlo theme requires some plugins that are mandatory for this theme to work. One of those plugins is `Pixzlo core`. The moment I click on activate I get this error on screen (I have activated debugging in `wp-config.php`)

`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, string given in /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-content/plugins/pixzlo-core/admin/theme-config/config.php:3035 Stack trace: #0 /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-content/plugins/pixzlo-core/admin/theme-config/config.php(3035): in_array('archive', 'Archive') #1 /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-content/plugins/pixzlo-core/pixzlo-redux.php(41): require_once('/home/ec2319242...') #2 /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-content/plugins/pixzlo-core/pixzlo-redux.php(65): PixzloRedux->pixzloReduxInit() #3 /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-content/plugins/pixzlo-core/index.php(22): require_once('/home/ec2319242...') #4 /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2313): include_once('/home/ec2319242...') #5 /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(661): plugin_sandbox_scrape('pixzlo-core/ind...') #6 /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-content/themes/pixzlo/admin/welcome-page/welcome.php(31): activate_plugin('pixzlo-core/ind...') #7 /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): Pixzlo_Zozo_Admin_Page->pixzlo_admin_page_init('') #8 /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #9 /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #10 /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(175): do_action('admin_init') #11 {main} thrown in /home/prashantj/public_html/wp-content/plugins/pixzlo-core/admin/theme-config/config.php on line 3035`

How can I fix this error?

I have this website hosted on

```
AWS EC2 t2.micro free tier
Ubuntu 20.4
```

Comment: That's a paid theme, so you should contact support.

Comment: Did you used PHP 8 version? If yes the theme maybe not compatible with your PHP vesion and need to have some improvement

Comment: @Inazo Yes it is PHP version 8

Comment: Contact support to confirm PHP 8 is supported